# Separate knockout js file for each view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I was not able to find the best answer as an how to maintain knockout files in an mvc application.

I have an mvc application which have about 8-10 views.

I just have started with 2 views and can see that my knockout js file which I am using common for both view has grown considerably.

So I wanted to know what is the best practice of creating these files. Shall I create s separate knockout file for each view or should I create just one common for all my views.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is always to create separate files according to their purpose. 
You say you have 2 views, so you should also have 2 separate JS (viewModel) files, as well as a 3rd JS file if you need global variables and a way to transfer data between files.

> should I create just one common for all my views

-- Bad idea, because enterprise level applications can have over a 1000 views. At those levels bad coding standards can easily render it unusable.

At some point you will need to be aware of [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) and [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) to manage all your dependencies.

Further reading: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-large-maintainable-and-testable-knockoutjs-applications--net-30996 .

Comment: There is very little reason to use AMD in 2018 — Webpack (or any other ES2015 bundler) is a much better solution.